# Can I turn on PC with WOL by just entering on a web link?

Tags: android, web, wake-on-lan

I want to Turn ON my PC with Android Google Assistant and I need a web system that when I enter on a specific link, my PC will Power on. For this I thought That is a Website that offer me to fill IP Forms that generate a link which when I enter it, to start my pc through Wake On LAN. I want to use IFTTT with this system. Maybe you can help me.
Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wake on LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) doesn't work with TCP/IP.
To wake a computer, you need to use UDP to broadcast a package to a MAC address.

You can, however, start a UDP websocket from a Javascript API and send this magic broadcast packet as described on the wiki page above.

You can do two different things:

- Make a webpage that has Javascript which triggers the magic packet.
- Make an API that can trigger the magic packet.

In both cases you can make it so that the MAC address is passed onto the URL, and processed by the frontend/backend to send the magic packet to the relevant address.